# Tips about signal strength metering with percentage

Tags: signal, measurement

I'm working with a device that receives digital television signals in the range of **-40dBm** to **-100dBm**. My tuner component has some status register that will give me a value for the signal strength, and I can find a **lower saturation** and an **upper saturation** value (which would be my **0%** and **100%** signal strength).

I want to give the user a reliable signal strength feedback based in **percentage**.

What should I do? Should I map the register value to the signal strength values in dBm or in mW? Which will make more sense in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A log scale here feels much more intuitive to the average user than a linear scale, as long as you don't tire them (consumers) with dBm details.

If your range is -100 to -40 dBm, I'd map -100 to a small percentage, say 5% and -40 to 100%. That is assuming you can still receive a signal at -100dBm and you have a separate indicator that your receiver is not locked => 0%

So when locked:
$$percentage = \dfrac{19}{12}×register + 163\dfrac{1}{3}$$

When unclocked: 
$$percentage = 0$$

Comment: The answer would be better if more details were provided about why the user would find this more intuitive, but I guess it is related to the huge range that this kind of signal varies into.

Comment: dB's and other log scales are a way to 'translate' into ratio's. Every doubling of signal strength equals 6dB. A change in signal strength from 1mW to 2mW is is experienced entirely different than from 20mW to 21mW. dB's tackle this. Many of our senses (hearing, feeling, ...) have a similar sensitivity; you can feel the difference between a full mug of coffee and an empty one, but what if this mug of coffee is on top of a heavy shopping basket, will you still be able to feel the differenc?